# Listing parts of a class

Tags: ruby, class, variable-assignment, instance-variables, attr-accessor

I am trying to make a code with a cat, where you are able to buy certain toys and use them. However, whenever I try to list the toys in the "shop," it gives me an error every time. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it is definitely somewhere in how I'm executing the command.

```
class Toy
  attr_reader :name
  
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def shop
    puts "#{@Toy}"
  end
end

toy.shop
```

I am not sure how to properly run this command, but I'm fairly certain the problem is in the "toy.shop" line.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is, what file the problem is in, what line the problem occurs on, and what method the problem occurs in.

Comment: Yes, but I'm on replit as I am still new to this coding thing, and I have no clue what the errors mean. It says, "undefined local variable or method 'toy' for main:Object" That's probably like reading a picture book but I have no clue what it means or how to fix it.

Comment: Please, don't hide important information like this away inside a comment. The information required to answer the question should be in the question.

Comment: That's because *toy* is undefined. You don't invoke `toy = Toy.new("some name")` so the local variable doesn't exist. You can prove that by calling `defined? toy #=> nil`.

Answer (score 2):

### A Working Rewrite and Simplification

There are a number of issues with your current code. Since there's always more than one way to do almost anything in Ruby, you can do this in other ways, too. However, here are some key issues:

- You're not really leveraging #initialize.
- You don't instantiate a new Toy object with Toy#new.
- You don't assign Toy#new to a local *toy* variable.
- Because *toy* is not defined, it doesn't have access to any of Toy's instance methods like #shop.
- The non-existent *toy* variable is the receiver for the #shop method, so it will raise [NameError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/NameError.html) if *toy* is undefined, or [NoMethodError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/NoMethodError.html) if *toy* is defined but not an instance of the Toy class or another class that can respond to the #shop method.

Based on your limited example, I'd rewrite and simplify the code as follows:

```rb
class Toy 
  attr_accessor :name
  
  def shop
    p "You bought a #{@name}."                                                  
  end
end

toy = Toy.new
toy.name = "mouse"
toy.shop
#=> "You bought a mouse."
```

### Why Kernel#p Instead of Kernel#puts

Note that [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) will not only print your output to STDOUT, but will also return a value, which is extremely useful in a REPL or when debugging code. [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts), on the other hand, always returns `nil` so I generally prefer #p unless the output from #inspect is undesirable for some reason. Your mileage in that regard may vary.

### See Also

- The `defined?` [keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html).
- Variable [assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html).
- Ruby [syntax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax_rdoc.html).
- Ruby [exceptions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a class, you should initialize and then call the method like this: `Toy.new('some_toy').shop`

And there is an error in your `shop` method, `@Toy` doesn't exists.
It should be:

```
  def shop
    puts "#{@name}"
  end
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but is there a way to only have it display when there is a toy.shop command run?

Comment: I think you are thinking about a Model, not a Class. In this example you are only initializing a Toy with a name and displaying it . If you want to save it on the database and list it later, you should read about Rails and Models here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html